# I want to assign Object field eg. greeting.method (which can be post or get ) to Form Method attribute using thymeleaf spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-webflow

Generally the code is -->

[Image of code, click here to see the code!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P5Ad.png)

I want that method which is hardcoded as "post" need to come from greeting object eg. (greeting.method)

How can I achieve that any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand your question (it is not very well formulated). If you want to save your object from thymeleaf via post request here is a good guide https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-in-spring-mvc

Comment: Hi asgarav, thankyou for reply, what i want to say is in form (HTML) <tag> for attributes action and url i want value to get it from object not hardcoded eg. <form th.action= "@{/save}" method = "post"> instead of that can i have something like <form action = {gretting.href} method = {gretting.href} > [this is sample which i'm looking for ]

Answer (score 0):

So just to make it clear, you want to read the url action and method from a variable, instead of hardcoding them in thymeleaf

In that case that is actually very simple:

1. Pass url and method variables to the model by defining the following in your controller

   `@ModelAttribute("url") public String url() { return "foo/bar"; }`

   `@ModelAttribute("method") public String method() { return "POST"; }`
2. Define the url and method with thymeleaf: `<form th:action="${url}" th:method="${method}" ...>`